# jQuery Validation plugin not working with file input element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin to limit the user to certain file types. As of now, it accepts any and all files, no matter what I do. I call it like this:

```
    $("#untForm").validate({
      ignore: [],
        rules: {
            fileName: {
                required: false,
                extension: "jpg|gif|png|mov|avi|pdf"
            }
        }
    });
```

and here is part of my form:

```
<input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" name="attachment" id="attachment" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value"   />
```

I've also tried this:

```
<input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" name="attachment" id="attachment" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value" accept=" "image/x-jpg, image/x-png, image/x-gif, application/pdf"  />
```

In the case below, if I use the extension parameter, it accepts any type of file!

```
$("#untForm").validate({
         ignore: [],
            rules: {
                fileName: {
                    required: false,
                    extension: "png|jpe?g|gif"
                }
            }
        });
```

Does anyone see anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Does anyone see anything wrong?"*

Yes...

```
rules: {
    fileName: {  // <- no such element with this name
        ....
```

It's simply not working because you don't have any file `input` element with the attribute `name="fileName"`.

You **must** assign the rule using the `name` attribute of the relevant file `input` element.

If it's `name="attachment"` as per your question's HTML markup, then your jQuery needs to look like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#untForm").validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            attachment: { // <- name of input
                required: false,
                extension: "png|jpe?g|gif"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the inline JavaScript, but you don't need a `onchange` handler for jQuery Validate to function properly.  *(actually, with jQuery, you'll never need to use an inline event handler again)*

```
<input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" name="attachment" id="attachment" />
```

**Working DEMO of your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/yb9A8/**

Comment: Ok makes sense.  Here is my button - I'm doing it this way as I really want the user to click on an icon to select their attachment;
  <input type="text" id="fileName" name="fileName"  title="Attach a file of type .jpg, .png, .gif, .pdf, .mov, .avi" >
   <div class="file_input_div">
   <input type="hidden" value="attachment" class="file_input_button"><aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe003;">
                    <input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" name="attachment" id="attachment" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value"

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to enter a longer reply...  I actually submit the form later, after I take a screenshot.  I'm wondering if this is affecting the way the validation is working..

Comment: @user1309220, I correctly identified your problem as per the code you posted and demonstrated the solution in my jsFiddle. If that doesn't work because you failed to show enough code, then please edit your OP.  Posting code in comments is not helpful to anyone. Then I'll gladly take a second look.

Comment: @user1309220, from what I see in your comment however, you cannot validate the `type='hidden'` input.  jQuery Validate can only validate `<input type='text'>`, `<input type='radio'>`, `<input type='checkbox'>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements.  The `ignore: []` option was only meant to validate those allowed elements when they are hidden or invisible.